# Parameters: Twin cover and Vertex cover

Tags: np-hardness, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

I am a research scholar, currently working on parameterized algorithms. I am working on a problem and have been exploring various parameters for which the problem remains unsolved. I have read the following paper on formulating fixed parameter tractable algorithms for Twin cover.

1.*Ganian, Robert*, [**Twin-cover: beyond vertex cover in parameterized algorithmics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-28050-4_21), Marx, Dániel (ed.) et al., Parameterized and exact computation. 6th international symposium, IPEC 2011, Saarbrücken, Germany, September 6–8, 2011. Revised selected papers. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-28049-8/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 7112, 259-271 (2012). [ZBL1352.68105](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1352.68105).

Even though i understand all the techniques described in this paper, I did not understand how a problem is fixed parameter tractable with respect to a larger parameter(vertex cover in this case) if it is fixed parameter tractable with respect to a smaller parameter(twin cover in this case). The problem i am working on is proved to be fixed parameter tractable with respect to the vertex cover and it is open when parameterized by twin cover. Could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: If a problem is fpt wrt a smaller parameter, it is also fpt wrt a larger parameter. E.g., if you have an efficient algorithm for graphs with twin cover $\le k$, then you also have an efficient algorithm for graphs with vertex cover $\le k$, as any such graph must have twin cover $\le k$ as well, hence you can apply the first algorithm. In general, no such reduction works in the opposite direction.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a pair $(Pb,d)$ formed by a NP-hard decision problem $Pb$ and two parameters / measures of difficulty $d(I)$  and $d'(I)$ on any legal input $I$ for it, in additional to its size $n(I)$. Assume that the worst case complexity of $Pb$ is non decreasing with $n$, $d$ and $d'$. Let's establish some basic notions:

- Saying that $Pb$ can be solved in time within $O(t(n))$ means that there is an algorithm which runs in time within $O(t(n))$;
- Saying that $Pb$'s worst case complexity is within $\Omega(t(n))$ (i.e. in $\Theta(t(n))$ if it is also within $O(t(n))$) means that no algorithm can ALWAYS run in time within $o(t(n))$;
- Saying that $Pb$ is in $NP$ means that correctness of a certificate of its output can be checked in time polynomial in $n$;
- Saying that $Pb$ is $NP$-hard means that other problems from $NP$ can be reduced in time polynomial in $n$ to $Pb$, such that if $Pb$ could be solved in time polynomial in $n$, all $NP$ problems could too;
- Saying that $Pb$ is fixed parameter tractable with respect to a parameter $d(I)$ (i.e. $(Pb,d)\in FPT$) means that there is an algorithm solving $Pb$ which running time is polynomial in the input size $n$ in the worst case   over all instances with a FIXED value of $d(I)$ (e.g. $t(n)=n^d$ is polynomial in $n$ for fixed values of $d$, while $d^n$ is not).

Say that

1. $d(I)\leq d'(I)$  on any legal instance $I$ of $Pb$, and that
2. $(Pb,d)\in FPT$:

Then

- according to (2.), there is an algorithm solving $Pb$ which running time is polynomial in $n$ over all instances with a fixed value of $d(I)$;
- according to (1.), this algorithm is solving $Pb$ in time polynomial in $n$ over all instances with fixed value of $d'(I)$, since $d(I)\leq d'(I)$ and a fixed value of $d'(I)$ will put an upper bound on $d(I)$

So that $(Pb,d')\in FPT$.
The reverse implication is not true.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, I was wondering whether there is any content or papers on proving W[1]-hardness for a problem when parameterized by the Twin cover, I don't seem to find any. How one may proceed in solving this? any suggestions will be helpful. TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a specialist on Parameterized Complexity, and even less about (the size of the) twin cover as a parameter.